# Deploy .war file on a server (Liferay+Tomcat Bundle)

Tags: liferay, war

I have my new Liferay site ready and trying to test it in a real environment. I just got Tomcat-Liferay bundle installed on my server successfully and copied the .war file into the deploy directory next to tomcat according to instructions from some forums and comments; but after going to the URL, I still see the default Liferay page and my page doesn't get diplayed. What an I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the .war? Is it a portlet, theme, hook?

Comment: or is this .war file a standalone web-application?

Comment: Sorry guys. It's a theme, the whole website. Maybe I should copy all the contents of the theme war into the ROOT under webapps under tomcat or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working. Drop them.war file into the deploy folder next to tomcat folder, and if there is a database other than Liferay's own database, define its parameters in the portal-ext.properties file. Also if you have saved any files in the data folder next to tomcat, you might need to import that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Deploying a theme or portlet plugin doesnt change the way the portal looks by default. You have to apply the theme on a page or set of pages after deployment. Similarly for portlet you should add the portlet on a page after deployment.

Coming back to your question, since it is a theme, once the the theme is deployed, login to Liferay, click on Manage Pages. You should see Look and Feel tab at two levels. One is the page set level that is for all the pages in that group whether public or private and the other is page level, that is just for one page.

Click on Look and Feel tab based on your requirement(whether you want the theme to be applied on all the pages or just a single page). Here you should see the current theme that is applied(by default it should be classic theme) and Available themes. Your new theme should be visible in Available themes section. Just click on your theme and the look and feel of your portal page or pages should change.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it well:) I have the whole website ready built in Eclipse and on a virtual machine. I have now exported the .war file for that theme and want to put it on a real server for the public to see. So there is no more work required on my website. The .war file is the final ready package. I hope I have been able to explain things clearly. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to tell that you have created a website with liferay which you want to move to another server?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry for my bad explanation:)

Comment: There are many way, if it is just CMS with no custom portlets and custom data, then you can use liferay's LAR import/export or Staging feature. If you need the data too, then its better to migrate the data to the database which is being used by your other portal. You also need to copy the data folder available in bundle.

Comment: This is a public website. During development I configured a database (mysql) for it. I also have custom portlets if by those you mean for example a cutomized navigation portlet or a custom login portlet. I copied the data folder next to tomcat folder and the content of the theme war file to the webapps/ROOT under tomcat. It gives me "HTTP Status 404" message and that 'resource not available'. Any other thing I am missing?